Dot accent on letter not being italicized
I want to use this statement in my document:

The word ‘right’ originates from Old English ġeriht.

The word 'ġeriht' with a dot accent on the letter 'g' is supposed to be italicized. When I use this code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fbb}

\begin{document}
The word `right' originates from Old English \textit{\.{g}eriht}.
\end{document}

It produces the below with the dot accent on the letter 'g' of the word 'ġeriht' without italicization like the dot on the letter 'i'.

How do I change the code so that the dot accent is also italicized along with the word?

Note the only effect of \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} is to produce a warning saying that it should not be used. You do not need inputenc unless you have a very old latex.

That's the shape in the font, so it's a font designer's choice.

By the way, using utf8x is deprecated. Remove the whole inputenc line.

Thanks a lot, mate!
